# Extending the Diffie-Hellman protocol to multiple parties

Tags: cryptography

I'm going through a Coursera cryptography class, and there appeared an interesting (and currently open) problem about extension of Diffie-Hellman protocol to multiple parties, while preserving the property of non-interactivity (i.e. no need for any exchange of information except the value $g^{a_{party}}$, which is a property of DH).

While I'm in no way a great mathematician, I decided I'd still try to think on this problem a bit. I have a feeling that the general construction is not secure, and try to build proof-by-contradiction for it.

Not going into details, I've broken down the problem to the following conditions:

We have some irreversible function $f(x)$ (i.e. for which a prototype $x$ can't be obtained from known $f(x)$) and a following function $F_f$:

\begin{align}
\forall i,j \in [1,n], \; n \in \mathbf{N}, &\; n>2, \; a_i \in \mathbf{R}:\\
F_f(a_i,f(a_1),\ldots,f(a_{i-1}),f(a_{i+1}),\ldots,f(a_n)) &= F_f(a_j,f(a_1),\ldots,f(a_{j-1}),f(a_{j+1}),\ldots,f(a_n));\\
F_f(\ldots,f(a_i),f(a_j),\ldots) &= F_f(\ldots,f(a_j),f(a_i),\ldots)
\end{align}

My question is: what can be inferred from such properties of function $F$? Can it be proven that given the $F_f$ we somehow can "break" the irreversibility of function $f$?

It's a completely open-ended question without a definite answer, I'm just looking for ideas.

Comment: Your conditions look a bit abstract to me. Would you mind giving an example of what the $f$, $F_f$, $a_i$ would be in normal, two-party Diffie-Hellman?

Comment: In case of normal Diffie-Hellman, $f(x) = g^x\mod{p}$, and $F_f(a_1,f(a_2)) = f(a_2)^{a_1}\mod{p} = g^{a_1*a_2}\mod{p}$ (we assume that $g$ is "globally" fixed). So, regardless of order of passing $a_1,a_2$ to $F_f$ we get the same key for both parties.

Comment: Sorry for many edits, didn't quite got hold of TeX syntax :)

Comment: Alright, so $F_f(a_1, f(a_2)) = f(a_2)^{a_1} = f(a_1)^{a_2} = F_f(a_2, f(a_1))$. But how would you begin defining $F_f(a_1, f(a_2), f(a_3))$? And why do you think it holds that knowing $F_f$ allows us to break the irreversibility of $f$? (In the case of $n = 2$, we *know* what the function $F_f(a,b) = b^a$ is, yet we cannot compute $x$ from $g^x$.)

Comment: That's exactly what I'm trying to find out. I have an intuition that this mix-up property ($F(a_1,f(a_2),f(a_3)) = F(a_1,f(a_3),f(a_2))$, which obviously cannot be formulated for DH where $n = 2$) will allow to break the abstract protocol. So, basically, I'm trying to build a proof by contradiction for abstract protocol defined by $f$ and $F_f$.

Comment: Building the exact pair $f,F_f$ is also out of question, obviously. Forgot to add also that I'm looking for proof on non-interactive protocols only, i.e. where there can be no exchange between parties except "posting" some derived values $f(a_i)$ to public source (noninteractivity being the main property of DH). I'll edit the question.

Comment: m.se is for closed-ended questions with definite answers.

Comment: This is [already answered over on Crypto.se](http://crypto.stackexchange.com/questions/1025/can-one-generalize-the-diffie-hellman-key-exchange-to-three-or-more-parties).

Comment: @mikeazo: Not this one exactly :) The protocol in the answer you linked is interactive (it can't be used e.g. by posting the exchange messages on Facebook, like DH allows). I'm looking strictly at non-interactive protocols, hence my formulation.

Comment: @GerryMyerson feel free to report it if you think so...

Comment: @DarkWanderer I stand corrected. Crypto.SE might be a better place for this question. I'll let you decide. As you say it is kind of open ended w/o a definitive answer. I can't predict how the community there will react to the question.

Comment: Yes, I just thought the math community is a better place for a question reduced to purely mathematical form. Thank you for the hint, regardless. Maybe I'll try.